# Can't install @angular/cli on mac sierra

Tags: angular, angular-cli, macos-sierra

I just don't understands why it doesn't work...

```
Aleksandrs-Mini:~ aleksandr$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/cli@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aleksandr/.npm/_logs/2017-08-11T23_07_00_964Z-debug.log
```

> Aleksandrs-Mini:~ aleksandr$ npm version
>
> { npm: '5.3.0',   ares: '1.10.1-DEV',   http_parser: '2.7.0',   icu:
>   '58.2',   modules: '48',   node: '6.11.2',   openssl: '1.0.2l',   uv:
>   '1.11.0',   v8: '5.1.281.103',   zlib: '1.2.11' }

I can install scoped packages like @types/angular, and all other packages work..

Comment: Is it possible you're using a custom npm registry? What happens when you run it with `--registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`?

Comment: Aleksandrs-Mini:~ aleksandr$ npm install -g @angular/cli --registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/cli@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aleksandr/.npm/_logs/2017-08-12T06_56_15_538Z-debug.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found solution:

I'm using private npm repository at `bintray`.So i had to provide credentials for it and these credentials were written in npm config.I removed `auth section` in it and now it works.

run this command and edit: `npm config edit`